# Whats the importance of chunk when importing large amount of data in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand why chunking data is effective when importing (or export) large amount of data in mysql. I've found a lot of blogs showing how to chunk large data, but I can't find any explanation about it. Is it important when handling large amount of data? Does it make importing time shorter? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps you check where you're at with the restore, and can make data available incrementally rather than all at once.

If you don't chunk it could take 48h to restore all the data and you have no idea if it'll work until you get to 48h, as at 47h59m it could still go horribly wrong.

If you had chunks that take 10-20m to restore you can see how it's progressing and recover from failures more quickly.

Comment: It is safer if you chunk data?!

Comment: Safer? Depends on what your concerns are. Both methods work. The one-chunk method is just more error-prone.